# How can I pad a number with zeros in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to execute this kind of a query:

```
SELECT 00005
```

Now its result showing as 5. It not taking '0000'. How to get the correct value. Any body can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

00005 is not a number, but it is a string...

```
SELECT '00005'
```

Comment: That is not giving an answer.

Comment: 5 people disagree with you. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, it is. But you know what is he asking for and did not provide an answer, right? Your is a comment, not answer.

Comment: No, we don't know that simply selecting the value in quotes does not solve his problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function:

```
SELECT LPAD(5, 5, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a ZEROFILL property, e.g. -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  column1 INT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT NULL
);

SELECT * FROM table1;
+---------+
| column1 |
+---------+
|   00005 |
|   00025 |
+---------+
```